# Linewidth and edgecolor in a barplot

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I discovered strange behavior in Matplotlib 2.1.0 (Python 3.6). Is this a bug?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# data
x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
y = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

# I would expect two identical figures
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1,2)
ax1.bar(x, y, edgecolor='red', linewidth=2)     # Is this a bug?
ax2.bar(x, y, edgecolor=['red']*5, linewidth=2) # This is what I expected

fig.show()
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I'm sure I've seen this reported as a bug with version 2.1.0, but I can't seem to find it...

Comment: With matplotlib2.0.2 and python 2.7 the first case works well

Comment: Found it https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/9351. Looks like it will be fixed in version 2.1.1